# Renaming the images in ipad and then saving that image to app bundle?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am creating an app in which i am displaying images from photo library and app bundle by clicking on two separate action buttons.

Now what i want is that i want to create a new action button and its purpose will be to select an image from photo library and then save that image into my app bundle.

Can anyone guide me to right direction regarding this topic.

Thanks,
Christy

Comment: do you want paths or how to take image from the displaying one..

Comment: Thanks for responding,i have to select images from the existing images in photo library and yes for that purpose i must know the url of the images and i know them .now i want to save these images to app bundle ,please tell how to save in app bundle using urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can modify the application bundle once it's on the iPhone. The entire thing is code signed, and changing it would cause it to not run any more. You can try saving the image to documents directory.

So far as I know you cannot repackage the bundles on the iPhone once your app has been released to the App Store. So go the other way, and put the data from the bundle on the filesystem so you can change it at runtime.

My usual technique for this stuff is:

1. bundle up the initial data
2. have a routine that checks for the
   presence of a versioned file on the
   iPhone's filesystem at startup
3. if that routine doesn't find the
   current version of the file, copy
   all the data into the iPhone's
   filesystem
4. reference the data from the
   filesystem in my app, rather than
   using the bundle path

So, essentially your bundle is just a delivery mechanism, a way to preload the filesystem with the stuff you are going to need. Once it's on the filesystem you can change anything you wish.

References

[Downloading image into bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711115/downloading-image-into-bundle)

[How to save a UIImage to the application's Bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332437/how-to-save-a-uiimage-to-the-applications-bundle)

**UPDATE**

```
- (IBAction)saveImage:(UIImage *)image {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);// Change according to your needs
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];   
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure friend for this??

Comment: Yes I think so. I have added the references. Pls check that too

Comment: Thanks a lot you made my day,now i can look into the other task.

Comment: can u tell me how to add images to my documents directory

Comment: check the update portion in my answer. Accept the answers that helped you first ok.

Comment: but i want to save the image by the text in my lael,fo rthat shall i change path component as:label.text

Comment: the name you give for the file to be saved is according to your needs. You can change it as u wish

Comment: I mean if i said rose then rose will be displayed in my label and then i want to save the image as rose.png so is it ok to change the path component ther as rose.png

Comment: its not working ,when i click the save image action button ,the applicatio is crashing out,do i have to add any more lines then what u have said

Comment: I am not getting friend i am very much new to this plx help

Comment: what is the crash? check the console and see what causes the crash

Comment: Not getting it ,when i click on the save image button the button stays like being clicked for 3 seconds then the application is automatically closed,,i m testing this in simulator now

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: copy the details from the console

Comment: cant copy here its a long display

Comment: well what does it say? you can paste in your question

Comment: can u give me your code for copying images from library to bundle ,i will find that out

Comment: I dont have a code for that. Just provide us with the exception. Just update your question with the crash log

Comment: NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);/ this code is where my app is strucking please help

Comment: you can try NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

Answer (score 0):

You can make an NSData from the image you are picking from your photo library by using this -

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation (UIImage *image,CGFloat compressionQuality);
```

then call

```
[imageData writeToFile:imgPath atomically:YES];
```

Here imgPath is the path for TMP dirextory where you want to write the file, get it as -

```
NSString *filename = @"a.png";

NSString *uniquePath = [TMP stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
```

and TMP is an enum

```
#define TMP NSTemporaryDirectory()
```

Comment: mine is an speechrecognition app when i speak "rose" an image of rose is being displayed and in my library i have image of rose ,now what i want is this image of rose is being saved to app bundle as "ROSE.png".will this code of yours will serve that purpose to me.in that NString *filename i have to give the text entered in my text field to save that image as the desired name.Is it so?

Comment: @Christina you cann't save files to app bundle because the app bundle is signed the with SSL certificate, you cann't change it. You can write your file to TMP or document directory. The above code writes file to TMP. If you want how to get document directory path then let me know?

Comment: @saadnib -yes,i want to know how to get document directory path.

Comment: you can get it as, i m using it for getting database path - NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    
    databasePath = [[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName] retain];

Comment: Thanks a lot saadnib for this,now can u help me with playing movie clip in my app

Comment: To play movie clip you can follow the tutorail - http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-playing-video-with-the-mediaplayer-framework/

Comment: can u tell me how to add images in documents directory

Comment: You should read AVFoundation framework of apple for this.Try this from developer.apple.com.

Comment: NSString *imagePath = [[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName] retain]; by using this you can get the path where you can add image, then in my answer make a NSData from that image and call writeToFile on NSData.