# How to debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

```
    2011-04-26 01:36:17.914 Protoype_Test1[15119:207] -[Protoype_Test1ViewController saveImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f60e60
    2011-04-26 01:36:17.933 Protoype_Test1[15119:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Protoype_Test1ViewController saveImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f60e60'
    *** Call stack at first throw:
    (
      0   CoreFoundation                      0x0126cbe9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
      1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x010615c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
      2   CoreFoundation                      0x0126e6fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
      3   CoreFoundation                      0x011de366 ___forwarding___ + 966
      4   CoreFoundation                      0x011ddf22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
      5   UIKit                               0x00366a6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
      6   UIKit                               0x003f51b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
      7   UIKit                               0x003f7647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
      8   UIKit                               0x003f61f4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
      9   UIKit                               0x0038b0d1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
      10  UIKit                               0x0036c37a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
      11  UIKit                               0x00371732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
      12  GraphicsServices                    0x01a83a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
      13  CoreFoundation                      0x0124e064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
      14  CoreFoundation                      0x011ae6f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
      15  CoreFoundation                      0x011ab983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
      16  CoreFoundation                      0x011ab240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
      17  CoreFoundation                      0x011ab161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
      18  GraphicsServices                    0x01a82268 GSEventRunModal + 217
      19  GraphicsServices                    0x01a8232d GSEventRun + 115
      20  UIKit                               0x0037542e UIApplicationMain + 1160
      21  Protoype_Test1                      0x00001c34 main + 102
      22  Protoype_Test1                      0x00001bc5 start + 53
    )
    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: Hello Christina, besides those kind of posts are not very welcome, could you **please** rather provide your code than the outcome?

Comment: "Please help" is an error message?

Comment: i think you need to rewire the flux capacitor, at a guess

Comment: The important line is `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Protoype_Test1ViewController saveImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5f60e60'
`

Comment: Oh jesus....! Who will read all that stuff...nobody have that much of time... be specific

Comment: yes and what i have to do to resolve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if the `IBAction` of the buttons are connected properly. I guess they are not properly connected

Comment: In the answer I gave for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785890/renaming-the-images-in-ipad-and-then-saving-that-image-to-app-bundle/5786277#5786277 saveImage method has a parameter of type UIImage but i think u missed it

Comment: i have writed the method as u told in action button ,wont this will get called as soon as click the button

Comment: Could you post the line where you call the method ?

Comment: - (IBAction)saveImage:(UIImage *)image

Comment: how can i retrieve the image here

Comment: - (void)saveImage:(UIImage *)image call this method inside your button action

Comment: `- (IBAction)buttonPressed{[self saveImage:yourImageToBeSaved];}`

Answer (score 0):

It would be much helpful if you post your source code rather than error out come.

Anyway i think you are trying to call an instance method through class reference.
The problem is here:

```
[Protoype_Test1ViewController saveImage]
```

It should be:

```
[protoype_Test1ViewController saveImage]
```

This is a common mistake when relay much on auto complete.